# Can anyone help me showing that the algebra of subsets of $X\times Y$ generated by $R$ is the union of finite elements in $R$?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

The problem goes like this:
Let $(X,\mathscr{A})$ y $(Y,\mathscr{B})$ measure spaces. Let  $R\colon=R(\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B})$ the collection of measurable rectangles
$
R\colon =\{A\times B\colon A\in\mathscr{A},B\in\mathscr{B}\}.
$
Prove that the algebra of subsets of $X\times Y$ generated by $R$ is the collection of finite unions of elements of $R$.
I have a hint and it is in which I call $C$ to be the collection of finite unions of elements of $R$, prove that $C$ is in the algebra generated by $R$, then prove that $C$ is an algebra that contains $R$.

Comment: look at Parthasarathy's measure theory book.  They go over this

Answer (score 0):

You only need to prove that the set $\mathcal{A}$ of finite disjoint unions of elements of $R$ is an algebra.

Note that $R$ has the following properties:
$$\emptyset \in R,$$
$$E, F \in R \implies E \cap F \in R,$$
$$E \in R \implies E^c \text{ is a finite disjoint union of members of } R.$$
Any set $R$ that satisfies the above three hypotheses has the property that the algebra generated by $R$ is the collection of finite disjoint unions of elements of $R$. This is not difficult to verify.